# Delete all rows with an empty cell anywhere in the table at once in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have googled it and found lots of question in stackoverflow. So suppose I have a dataframe like this

```
A  B
-----
1  
   2
 
4  4
```

First 3 rows will be deleted. And suppose I have not 2 but 200 columns. How can I do that?

Comment: Is it `df.dropna()`?

Comment: This should be right, and he shouldn't need to specify how='any' and axis=0 since these are the defaults.

Comment: @LiamFiddler But I also want to replace emoty space with `na` first?

Comment: No, Pandas will interpret the blanks as NA values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your request - first replace to Nan:

```
df = df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
df = df.dropna()
```

If you want to remove on a specific column, then you need to specify the column name in the brackets

Comment: But  you need to convert those empty places to 'na' first right?

Comment: I have edited the solution. But this is not necessary